# How do i send a single message to multiple ip?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

When ip contains a json-type,
Among the current connection to `factory.getConnectionIds()` to find the corresponding IP.
Then set the header to send the logic during development.

Through `factory.getConnectionIds()` found the IP list that is currently connected, I set up a header. but `unable to find outbound socket` error is occured.

What is the cause?

integration config is...

```
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter sslAdapter() {
    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
    adapter.setConnectionFactory(sslServerFactory());
    adapter.setOutputChannel(inputWithSSL());

    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public TcpSendingMessageHandler sslHandler() {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    handler.setConnectionFactory(sslServerFactory());

    return handler;
}

@Bean
public AbstractConnectionFactory sslServerFactory() {
    int port = Integer.parseInt(inboundPort);
    TcpNioServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNioServerConnectionFactory(port);
    factory.setBacklog(BACKLOG);
    factory.setTaskExecutor(taskSchedulerWithSSL());
    factory.setLookupHost(false);

    factory.setSerializer(echoSerializer);
    factory.setDeserializer(echoSerializer);

    factory.setTcpNioConnectionSupport(tcpNioSSLConnectionSupport());

    // Nagle's algorithm disabled
    factory.setSoTcpNoDelay(true);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowForReceiveSslMessage() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(sslAdapter)
            .<byte[], Boolean>route(
                    p -> (short) 0 == ByteBuffer.wrap(p, 0, BYTE_LENGTH_OF_SHORT).getShort(),
                    m -> m.channelMapping(TRUE, INPUT_WITH_SSL_JSON)
                            .channelMapping(FALSE, INPUT_WITH_SSL_ECHO)).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowForExtractingSslJson() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(inputWithSslJson())
            .handle(INBOUND_SERVICE, EXTRACT_PAYLOAD_AS_JSON)
            .<Map<String, Object>, String>route(
                    p -> (String) p.get(REQUEST),
                    m -> m.channelMapping(LOGIN, INPUT_WITH_SSL_LOGIN)
                            .channelMapping(LOGOUT, INPUT_WITH_SSL_LOGOUT)
                            .channelMapping(POLICY, INPUT_WITH_SSL_POLICY)
                            .channelMapping(PUSH_TARGET, INPUT_WITH_SSL_PUSH_TARGET).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowForHandlingSslNotifyPolicyUpdate() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inputWithSslPushTarget()).handle(POLICY_SERVICE, RESPONSE_POLICY_UPDATE)
            .split(POLICY_SERVICE, SPLIT_MESSAGES)
            .channel(outputWithSslJsonBytesToClient()).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowForConvertingSslJsonToBytesAndSendClient() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(outputWithSslJsonBytesToClient())
            .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
            .handle(INBOUND_SERVICE, ATTACH_HEADER_BY_STRING).handle(sslHandler).get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outputWithSsl() {
    return MessageChannels.queue(POOL_SIZE).get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel inputWithSslJson() {
    return MessageChannels.queue(POOL_SIZE).get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel inputWithSslPushTarget() {
    return MessageChannels.queue(POOL_SIZE).get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outputWithSslJsonBytesToClient() {
    return MessageChannels.queue(POOL_SIZE).get();
}
```

RESPONSE_POLICY_UPDATE and SPLIT_MESSAGES is...

```
@Override
public Object responsePolicyUpdate(Object payload) throws Exception {
    log.debug("notify policy update debug : {}", payload);
    Map<String, Object> params = initParam(payload);
    Map<String, Object> result = initResult(params);
    result.put(RESPONSE, PUSH_TARGET);
    result.put(RESULT, SUCCESS);
    result.put(REASON, 0);

    return result;
}

@Splitter
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Message<String>> splitMessages(Object payload) throws Exception {
    log.debug("split messages debug : {}", payload);
    Map<String, Object> params = initParam(payload);
    List<String> pushTargetList = (List<String>) params.get(PUSH_TARGET_LIST); // pushTargetList is ip list.

    List<Message<String>> messageList = new ArrayList<Message<String>>();
    String[] conArray = new String[4];
    List<String> sslConnectionIds = sslServerFactory.getOpenConnectionIds();
    int sslPort = sslServerFactory.getPort();
    for (String con : sslConnectionIds) {
        log.debug("## con ip : {}", con);
        conArray = con.split(":");
        for (String pushTargetIP : pushTargetList) {
            if (conArray[0].equals(pushTargetIP)) {
                Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(params.toString())
                                        .setHeader("ip_connectionId", con).build();
                messageList.add(message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return messageList;
}
```

debug log is...
The first line is the current connection list.

```
2016-07-05 14:30:14.664 DEBUG 56092 --- [sk-scheduler-10] c.m.j.policy.service.PolicyServiceImpl   : ## con ip : 192.168.3.57:62370:5443:cdeb011d-91f5-46c4-abc9-b68ba13624b3

2016-07-05 14:30:14.672 DEBUG 56092 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : plainHandler received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[246], headers={sequenceNumber=1, json__TypeId__=class java.lang.String, sequenceSize=1, ip_connectionId=192.168.3.57:62370:5443:cdeb011d-91f5-46c4-abc9-b68ba13624b3, correlationId=fae71250-bf47-3f64-6ad3-1ce22ef69464, id=c6c097f0-9efb-f0a5-4240-924e06879b7f, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1467696614672}]
2016-07-05 14:30:14.672 ERROR 56092 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Unable to find outbound socket for GenericMessage [payload=byte[246], headers={sequenceNumber=1, json__TypeId__=class java.lang.String, sequenceSize=1, ip_connectionId=192.168.3.57:62370:5443:cdeb011d-91f5-46c4-abc9-b68ba13624b3, correlationId=fae71250-bf47-3f64-6ad3-1ce22ef69464, id=c6c097f0-9efb-f0a5-4240-924e06879b7f, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1467696614672}]
2016-07-05 14:30:14.673 DEBUG 56092 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket, headers={id=273f4477-52cf-645b-d157-e22dc7cc781a, timestamp=1467696614673}]
2016-07-05 14:30:14.673 DEBUG 56092 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : (inner bean)#6dc2279c received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket, headers={id=273f4477-52cf-645b-d157-e22dc7cc781a, timestamp=1467696614673}]
2016-07-05 14:30:14.675 ERROR 56092 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:113)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
at
...
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you sending or receiving TCP packets with this program?

Comment: Yes, of course
It is normal to receive request and response to the same ip.

Comment: It should work fine - you need to run in a debugger and examine the contents of the `TcpSendingMessageHandler`'s `connections` field.

Comment: Thanks Gary. It solved the problem. It issues to send data to a receiving 5001 plain port to the SSL port. It get solved by changing the port to the SSL port.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gary.
As you say, an error occurs in the method of  `handleMessageInternal` `TcpSendingMessageHandler` class.

Get `connectionId` is...

```
2016-07-06 10:04:28.704 DEBUG 30144 --- [ask-scheduler-4] c.m.j.policy.service.PolicyServiceImpl   : ## con ip : 192.168.3.57:53759:5443:bf93680b-13fe-401b-a1eb-5545917f404a
```

`connectionId` is not null. But, the result of `connections.get (connectionId)` is null.
This should not be understood.

This is the `TcpSendingMessageHandler` class...

```
/**
 * Writes the message payload to the underlying socket, using the specified
 * message format.
 * @see org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler#handleMessage(org.springframework.messaging.Message)
 */
@Override
public void handleMessageInternal(final Message<?> message) throws
        MessageHandlingException {
    if (this.serverConnectionFactory != null) {
        // We don't own the connection, we are asynchronously replying
        Object connectionId = message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID);
        TcpConnection connection = null;
        if (connectionId != null) {
            connection = connections.get(connectionId);
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error sending message", e);
                connection.close();
                if (e instanceof MessageHandlingException) {
                    throw (MessageHandlingException) e;
                }
                else {
                    throw new MessageHandlingException(message, "Error sending message", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.error("Unable to find outbound socket for " + message);
            throw new MessageHandlingException(message, "Unable to find outbound socket");
        }
        return;
    }
    else {
        // we own the connection
        try {
            doWrite(message);
        }
        catch (MessageHandlingException e) {
            // retry - socket may have closed
            if (e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Fail on first write attempt", e);
                }
                doWrite(message);
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `Message<String>` list...
The value obtained by `factory.getOpenConnectionIds()` method to get into the `ip_connectionId`.
Why not find a outboud socket?

```
GenericMessage [payload={result=success, reason=0, response=pushTarget}, headers={ip_connectionId=192.168.3.57:58187:5443:37702eaf-0bbc-44a1-8763-65e841a2f480, id=a1b80cc4-3f56-1b80-9c59-57be98b1031e, timestamp=1467783978378}]
GenericMessage [payload={result=success, reason=0, response=pushTarget}, headers={ip_connectionId=192.168.3.40:53161:5443:693c394c-d3dd-42a3-95ce-692a39a8b603, id=bb49ea99-5e3b-eccf-df3b-7ce03b4bbf73, timestamp=1467783978378}]
```